# timed jobs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, timer

I am writing a quick-and-dirty in-house ASP.NET application that needs to be able to run a task after a specific period of time. If it was a proper application, I'd probably use a windows service but I don't really want to bother with the extra complexity of that.

I could put code in the BeginRequest handler to check whether any such tasks are due, but of course nothing would happen if nobody is using the application.

at the moment the best option I can think of is something like `ShellExecute("nohup sleep 1000; wget http://server/dummypage.aspx")` (if you'll excuse the mixed windows/unix nomenclature).

Anyone have any bright ideas of an alternative?

Andy

Comment: If you are on windows server 2008, you can use powershell scripts to keep the application alive, in a similar way like shellExecute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Cache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) and expire it at the required time.

The [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41ttybaf.aspx) method has overloads that take a callback function, so you can use it as to location for the timed job.

Comment: Hey I like that idea - it's pure asp.net so keeps the architecture simple. I was thinking of doing something with session timeouts but this sounds more workable

Answer (score 0):

Write a console app that is ran at your set interval using a Windows Task?

This seems the most robust as you can usually set better intervals that the program will run at, such as the end of the Month etc.